# Put vertical space between pictures in Excel

Tags: excel, screenshot, vertical-alignment

I have several screenshots in Excel. I imported all of them at once from a folder. I need to align them vertically with 1 row space between each of them. Is there any easy way to do it?

It will be like:

- 1 screenshot
- 1 row
- 1 screenshot
- 1 row
- etc.

Screenshots in my Excel file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would put them align them diagonally, an additional column over and row down for each.

```
Row = 1
col = 1

For Each pic In Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures
    pic.Top = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(Row).Top
    pic.Left = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(col).Left
    Row = Row + 1
    col = col + 1
Next pic
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little adjustments to @ELW 's answer. This aligns all pictures to the left, puts them next to each other with 1 row space between.

```
lastTop = 0

For Each pic In Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures
    pic.Top = lastTop
    lastTop = lastTop + pic.Height + 15
    pic.Left = 0
Next pic
```